# How can I use pattern matching in Postgres

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, select

I have a basic tables of books like so:

```
CREATE TABLE books (
  id integer primary key,
  name text not null
);
INSERT INTO books (id, name) VALUES (1, 'The Ghost');
```

I want to search for a book name which matches the search term `^The Ghost$`. As you can see there is some regular expression in the term. How do I match via the regular expression?

I tried doing this but I got no results

```
select *
from books
WHERE name like '%^The Ghost$%'
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8a5aa6/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if your requirement really be verbatim to match `^The Ghost$`, then you may just use an equality comparison here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM books
WHERE name = 'The Ghost';
```

If you wanted to express the above using regex, you could use the `~` operator:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM books
WHERE name ~ '^The Ghost$';
```

Comment: Can `~` be used instead of `LIKE` for terms without any regex? Will it still be able to match partial book names

Comment: Answer: Maybe.  It depends on the regex/like expression.

Comment: Would `name LIKE '%The Ghost%'` be the same as `name ~ 'The Ghost'`

Comment: Yes, those two expressions in this case would match the same things.